# Stop iCloud to sync with a specific file

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization

I have a huge file (4.92GB) under synchronized folder. And I specifically do not want that file to sync with iCloud.

Is there any way to stop iCloud sync for that file or does it need to be moved to a non-syncing folder?

Comment: I’ve put the obvious workaround so someone can answer that and shortcut all the comments on that “solution”. You don’t have to accept that answer and can wait for someone to say no, this isn’t possible or yes, here’s how to trick the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add *.nosync* to the file (before the extension).

```
HugeFile.nosync.pdf
```

An icon (crossed out cloud) will indicate the exclusion.